# Make textbox visible true/false using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, asp.net

In my user control has  panel and panel has ddlType and txtOthers as text box controls, initially txtOthers is in visible false .

when user select in ddlType and its value (1,2,3,4,5 and 6) is equal to 6 , and the txtOthers make visible true else false.

I want to done this using JavaScript with IE8 to avoid postback.

any help!.

```
if (ddlType.value==6)
    txtOthers.Visible=true;
else
   txtOthers.Visible=false;
```

I have tried like above code, by default the control in in-visible so javascript  can not identify the control.

But , by default the control make visible false.

Comment: In javascript element's visibility may be set like this: `txtOthers.style.visibility = "visible";` (or `"hidden"`). And `textOthers.style.display = "block";` (or `"none"`)

Answer (score 0):

1. Make the control visible (by default should be visible)
2. hide the element using CSS style `display:none;` or `visibility:hidden;`
3. add an event listener to `ddlType` so when it becomes 6 you swap the style for txtOthers
4. also disable the auto post back for `ddlType`